# French speech to text using azure

Tags: python, azure, api, speech-to-text

I am using speech to text from Azure with Python.
I would like to use it in french but it didn't work out. For english, it works well but in french I don't know how to do it.
I am using Python 3.7.
I use the code written here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can give the source and target language

Comment: Where ? In which function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```py
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, 
                                   region=service_region, 
                                   speech_recognition_language="fr-FR")

audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=filepath)

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, 
                                               audio_config=audio_config)
result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

print(result.reason, result.text)
```